# CSS Border height is not in dynamic Internet Explorer

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have the following 3 screenshots of which the first 2 are from Chrome and the last one is from IE10. I've built the interface for a Query Builder. The first image shows the default view and on clicking the `+` button the view changes as shown in the second image.

[image]

[image: Google chrome screenshot]

Following is the CSS which I got for the border around the section.

```
.container_border {
    border: 2px solid rgb(148, 178, 73);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-top: none;
    margin: 0 -1px -1px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

When I tried the same thing in IE10, the border did not expand automatically and I'm not sure why.

Note: I'm not so fluent with CSS and I make use of Bootstrap for views. This is the first time I'm testing with IE, any best practices recommendations will be appreciated.

[image: IE10 screenshot]

Comment: It's hard to help without a test case. Try to make one: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can you check if `box-sizing: border-box` and remove it.